# OpenCV Canny Edge detector in Processing (Live video)

Tags: opencv, processing

I am currently working on a project that requires human body detection with a onboard camera. Long story short, I am now trying to do it using OpenCV canny edge detector.

All problem is that I can't really figure out how to apply detection for the captured video (well, for images there is example included in the library).

Maybe there is somebody who did it in Processing environment?

```
import processing.video.*;
import gab.opencv.*;

OpenCV opencv;
Capture cam;

PImage src, canny;

void setup(){
  size(640,480);

  cam = new Capture(this, 640/2,480/2);
  cam.start();
  opencv = new OpenCV(this, cam);
  opencv.findCannyEdges(20,75);
  canny = opencv.getSnapshot();

}

void draw(){
  pushMatrix();
  scale(2);
  image(cam, 0,0);
  image(canny, cam.width, 0);
  popMatrix();
}

void captureEvent(Capture c){
  c.read();
}
```

Comment: Can you link to the example?

Comment: @AbhijatBiswas , https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spektrr/OpenCV-edge-detection/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is the cv2.VideoCapture method.

Below is an example I did in Python but you should be able to transfer the usage.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray_vid = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    cv2.imshow('Original',frame)
    edged_frame = cv2.Canny(frame,100,200)
    cv2.imshow('Edges',edged_frame)
# Quit with 'Esc' key
    k= cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k==27:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Best regards / Colm